# How can we cache the MySQL query on the server side running java web application?

Tags: java, mysql, caching

Example:
If most clients require to fill the form which require selection of states and cities. So how could this query can be cached on the server side. Because the state or the city name hardly changes, so its good idea to cache them.

```
Table 1:
state_name  state_id
__________  ________
state1         1
state2         2

Table 2:
city_name   city_id   state_id
_________   _______   ________
city1          1         1
city2          2         1
city3          3         2
```

Comment: can you provide more information about your environment? there are about a billion and 1 ways to cache the results of a query on the server side...

Answer (score 3):

Create a `List<String>` of states and a `Map<String, String>` of [ city, state ] pairs and put it on the server as static, read-only data.  Load it from the database on startup.

I'd recommend a `WeakHashMap` as your implementation.  It'll give the GC a chance to evict values if absolutely necessary.

Number of states won't change, but cities list could be rather large.

Comment: This (load at startup) is exactly what we do, with a config object. We then do things like `config.getProperties("states")` (our "config" is _not_ a java `Properties` object, but we decided on getProperties as our method name anyway). Our config actually loads from various sources - the DB, some `.properties`, etc. - but the rest of the program doesn't care where those came from. We also have a "reload" method just in case any of these things _do_ change, so we don't have to re-launch to pick up the changes.

Comment: @duffymo can you please give an example with above data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't post code on command.  You ought to know how to do a SELECT with JDBC and map the results into a List or Map.  If you don't, you shouldn't be writing this app.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql by default will cache queries in its query cache - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

The cache of course has a finite size and so the results can be evicted if other queries are run - but if this query is executed frequently the mysql query cache may be sufficient for your needs.